# Cannot use diagnostic tools in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

When I try to debug my program and use the Diagnostic Tools window in Visual Studio 2019, I am presented with the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the message from the Diagnostics Hub Output:

```
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that the *Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150* was disabled. After re-enabling it, that problem has disappeared. To re-enable the service, I had to do the following:

1. Open Services

   1. Press `⊞` + `R`
   2. Type `services.msc`
   3. Click `OK`
2. Enable the *Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150*

   1. Find the *Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150* in the service list
   2. Right-click on its name
   3. Click `Start`

Comment: There was also a "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service" without the 150. I left this disabled and only enabled the 150 item. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You try remove Diagnostics package and reinstall it.
'Visual Studio Installer' > Modify > Individual components > uncheck ".net profiling tools, C++ profiling tools, Javascript diagnostics" => Modify. And 'check' again when it complete
work with me